# Is DBA the best place for questions related to SQL/DBA tools?

Tags: discussion, site-definition

Are questions about configuring or using SQL/DBA tool, such as SQL Studio, SQL Developer, TOAD, or phpMyAdmin, best posted on DBA?  If not, what is the best SE site for such?

The kind of question I have in mind relates to troubleshooting keep-alives and connectivity; it blurs into server admin and networking, and is not code or SQL-related.  The problem seems to be specific to SQL Studio, which is why I lean toward asking DBAs rather than, say, network admins on SU.

Comment: You have been using both SO and DBA for quite long...

Answer (score 7):

Good question.

Tools are officially on-topic here but of course it's a borderline area where there is overlap with SF, SO and even SU <sub>(but what exactly is/isn't on-topic at SU anyway?)</sub>.

In the end it's a judgement call: if you think your question will be *interesting to our experts* then I'd say 'ask here', that's the real criteria for an expert site like dba.se.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously it depends a bit more on the content of the question, but if it's a technical question (excluding coding specific questions) such as "how to use..." or "how do I configure..", I would post it on SU myself.