# Should DBA be the primary phpMyAdmin usage support channel?

Tags: discussion

The [phpMyAdmin support page](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/support/) points to stackoverflow.com and serverfault.com as the sole (non-bug related) support mechanism:

> ## Getting support
>
> Effective September 1st, 2013, support for questions directly related to phpMyAdmin has moved to stackoverflow. All prior support mechanisms have been phased out.
>
> Questions about server issues (web server configuration, "404 - Not Found" error, etc), should be asked on serverfault.com.
>
> The way of reporting (security) bugs and adding feature requests will be unaffected.

Since *usage* of DBA tools

- [are considered topical on DBA](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1127/is-dba-the-best-place-for-questions-related-to-sql-dba-tools)
- [art not topical on ServerFault](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/7963/clarification-on-off-topic-management-interfaces) (questions about installing/configuring the tools are topical, but not usage)
- [StackOverflow really isn't the right place for most phpMyAdmin usage questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263603/the-phpmyadmin-support-page-points-to-serverfault-com-as-a-primary-support-mecha/263604#263604), [unless it has to do with software development](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253394/third-party-development-support-hosted-by-stack-overflow)
- Usually don't fit into the [class of questions that are on-topic on Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

I think that DBA is the right SE site to direct phpMyAdmin *usage* questions, as opposed to SO, which is where they're being directed now. (At least by the [phpMyAdmin support page](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/support/).)

Comment: context is everything. if it's how to make phpMyAdmin work with a specific web server then it's not on-topic. if it's about how to use phpMyAdmin to accomplish a certain task then i believe it to be on-topic.

Comment: Also consider that if they consider that to be the official venue for support, they will probably be monitoring that tag there and actively answering questions, but not here...

Comment: @AaronBertrand My first step was to have the SE community out the appropriate site. My next step was to alert their community to the decision made here so that they can know what decision was made here.

Comment: @swasheck I agree entirely. I am not suggesting that all questions related to phpMyAdmin are on topic here, but I'm trying to figure out specifically which ones would be considered on topic, so that the right questions get asked at the right site. Currently, most configuration and usage questions get asked on SO (which shouldn't be happening, except when related to programming/development), and some get asked appropriately on SF. Fewer are asked here, and fewest are asked on Webmasters. The issue is that many usage questions are off-topic on SO, SF, and webmasters, but seem on-topic here.

Comment: @swasheck Given that many phpMyAdmin usage questions seem to be on-topic here, I'm trying to figure out if this community would feel that it's appropriate to have DBA being listed as a support channel for DBA related phpMyAdmin usage questions, ones having to do with DB operations, not website operations/interactions or installation/configuration help.

Answer (score 4):

While we don't mind them coming here, so long as they are actually DBA related topics, we aren't in the frequent habit of stealing content from SO to post here. If they feel this would be a preferable destination (as Aaron Bertrand points out in a comment, they are likely monitoring that tag now with an email system at least) then they may not want to split their efforts. Folks already know to goto SO for that help.

If the team maintaining that tool wants to send folks here, and they give us a heads up, I think we are fine with them showing up.

But here's the deal. I'm just a mod, I'm not the entire site. I'm not all the users. If others on the site think it will clutter things up, then let's not do it. But someone is going to have to voice the negative nancy side of things and back up the claims.

We will still close off-topic questions. We will still close crappy questions. We will still engage askers as professionals.

I for one am ok with this "merger". But we won't move existing SO content (altho the CM team or developers are welcome to do so at their discretion, natch).

Comment: I absolutely agree with everything that you bring up. The reason I'm looking at getting phpMyAdmin to change their product usage support site to here is because most questions related to their product usage are off topic at SO. "This has SQL code" does not a dev/programming question make, especially when the code is generated by a DBA tool. The only other place I can think of that would be appropriate is SU, the thought of which makes me cringe, but the distinction between pro and non-pro usage should have that split as well. I also know that one person does not a community make, and so I ask

Comment: and wait for comments and some sort of consensus to form before taking any actions.

Comment: This is not for [su] that's for sure. [SO] is still a valid landing site, but I agree that it's better to get more visibility into the other SE sites.